# Alternative locations for Hibernate mapping files?

Tags: java, hibernate, classpath, configuration-files

I just read an introductory tutorial on Hibernate that had all the mapping files inside the same source directory of the entities they represented:

```
TestProject/
    src/main/java/
        com.hibernate.tutorial.entities
            Student.java
            Student.hbm.xml

            Course.java
            Course.hbm.xml
```

etc. Normally, I like to place config files under `src/main/config`, and so ideally I'd like to have the following project directory structure:

```
TestProject/
    src/main/java/
        com.hibernate.tutorial.entities
            Student.java
            Course.java
    src/main/config
        hibernate/
            Student.hbm.xml
            Course.hbm.xml
```

Is there a way to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: Thanks @shevchik (+1) - can you provide an answer that gives an example of such annotations? **Very interested!**

Comment: http://loianegroner.com/2010/06/hibernate-3-annotations-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks again @shevchik but in that article there are no annotations that help bind a POJO/entity to a specific mapping XML file...

Comment: You don't need XML mapping. you just annotate pojo classes and mapping is ready

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-hello-world-example-annotation/

Comment: Thanks again @shevchik - if you include an answer for using annotations I'll happily give you the green check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to map Pojo class to hibernate entity:

1. XML mapping
2. Using annotations

Annotations becomes more prevalent last years.
Some examples you could find here:

[example1](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-hello-world-example-annotation/)

[example2](http://loianegroner.com/2010/06/hibernate-3-annotations-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Configuration.addDirectory( )`.

See also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addDirectory%28java.io.File%29

Comment: Thanks @Alexey (+1) - but let's say I'm executing this `Configuration.addDirectory(...)` from inside a JAR, and let's say that the `src/main/config/hibernate/**/*.hbm.xml` files all get stored to that JAR's `com` directory (`somejar.jar/com`). **How would I reference a `File` from inside the same JAR that I'm in?!?** Thanks again!